# Spotfire Line Chart Smoothing

Tags: spotfire, tibco

Download my .dxp dashboard [here](https://community.tibco.com/questions/line-graph-smoothing).

I have a line chart in Spotfire. On the x-axis is date and the y-axis is an amount. Specifically, it's the weighted average of a minimum amount for each date on x-axis. The y-axis expression is

```
WeightedAverage(
                [NUMERIC_1] , 
                 Min([NUMERIC_2]) over (Intersect([CAT_1],[CAT_2],[CAT_3]))
                )
```

The line is very jumpy so I'd like to smooth it. I thought of using the moving average expression, perhaps using a 7-day moving average. However, I'm not sure how to nest my WeightedAverage function (shown above) in the MovingAverage function because that's also a compound function.

Any ideas on how to smooth my line chart?

Comment: Could you please provide an example dataset?

Comment: @AndrewPruet I just added a link to my .dxp file with sample data.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a solution:

```
WeightedAverage([Weighting Factor],Min([NUMERIC_1]) over (Intersect([CAT_1],[CAT_2],[DATE_1]))) 
THEN Avg([Value]) OVER (LastPeriods(10,[Axis.X]))
THEN If(Count() OVER (LastPeriods(10,[Axis.X]))=10,[Value],null)
```